# Cannot open pdf file in browser using fpdf

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I am new to **fpdf**. In my application, if a user clicks on a link, then I create a pdf file and the file gets downloaded. But I wanted the file to be opened in the browser. Here is my code

```
$fpdf->Output("Circular.pdf", "I");
```

But the code isn't working. The browser is showing garbage. I don't know what I am doing wrong. In the attached image you can see the output that I can see in the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read up on the `Content-Type` header: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17